# Getting first value from a List into a DataRow for Excel

Tags: c#, datagridview

Using C# I am extracting Property values from an object into a DataGrid which works fine for simple data types.  However when there is a List I would like to extract just the first value, append an ellipsis and present with a tooltip informing the user to click to see the whole list.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
    public static DataTable ConvertListToDataTable<T>(List<T> list)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        foreach (PropertyInfo info in typeof(T).GetProperties())
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(info.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(info.PropertyType) ?? info.PropertyType));
        }
        foreach (T t in list)
        {
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();

            foreach (PropertyInfo info in typeof(T).GetProperties())
            {
                if (info.PropertyType.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(System.Collections.ICollection)))
                {
                    if(!info.GetValue(t,null).Equals(null))
                    {
                        row[info.Name] = String.Concat(info.GetValue(t, new object[]{ 0 }).ToString(), "...");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    row[info.Name] = info.GetValue(t, null) ?? DBNull.Value;
                }
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

The simple data types extract without any issues.

Having identified which Properties have a list I am struggling to extract the first value of the list. The code supplied throws an Exception:

```
info.GetValue(t, new object[]{ 1 })' threw an exception of type     'System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException'
base: {System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] index, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, Object[] index)}
```

Comment: What's the role of `Excel` in the question?

Comment: To show a `List<T>` in `DataGridView` you don't need to convert it to `DataTable`. Just assign it to `DataSource` of `DataGridView`.

Comment: The role of Excel is to present the Properties and allow them to be edited.  It is a Data Import tool so I guess that Excel was chosen because of its prevalence (I'm looking to enhance some legacy code here).  Based upon comments in the code the conversion to DataTable was for performance reasons but I will take a look into your suggestion Reza, thanks

Comment: `List<T>` is enough.